# When does MessageWebSocket receive data?

Tags: events, websocket, uwp

### Info: Despite using the `WebSocket` tag, I am using `MessageWebSocket` in my code because I am coding on UWP.

`MessageWebSocket` has an event called `MessageReceived`. I added an `TypedEventHandler` to this event when initializing the `MessageWebSocket`:

```
messageWebSocket.MessageReceived += new TypedEventHandler<MessageWebSocket, MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs>(OnMessageRecieved);
```

After sending data with a method called `SendData()`, I expected that the `MessageReceived` event is fired. But it won't and I don't know why.

This is my `SendData()` method:

```
private async void SendData(DataWriter dataWriter)
    {
        try
        {
            _evaLogger.Info("Trying to send data...");
            IBuffer buffer = dataWriter.DetachBuffer();
            await messageWebSocket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer);
            _evaLogger.Info("Data was sent");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _evaLogger.Error(e.Message, e);
        }
    }
```

If not after sending data, when does `MessageWebSocket` receive data?

Comment: How you implement your server side for your WebSocket? Could you share more details? Also, have you tried the official [WebSocket sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebSocket)? Dose it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out what the problem was. The server was expecting to get a text, instead I send data to the server. This is how the solution for sending text looks like:

```
private async Task SendData(DataWriter dataWriter)
    {
        try
        {
            _evaLogger.Info("Trying to send data...");
            await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
            _evaLogger.Info("Data was sent");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _evaLogger.Error(e.Message, e);
        }
    }
```

It's also important to set the the MessageType to Utf8:

```
messageWebsocket.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Utf8;
```